# TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not iterable

Tags: python, string, textbox

> Realizar una aplicación en python. Que escriba un texto en un textbox , lo analice en un botón de comandos y visualice en otro textbox el número de vocales que tiene la cadena original. sin importar si son mayúsculas o minúsculas

```
from tkinter import *

def obtener_vocales(mensaje):
    vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    return set ([c for c in mensaje if c in vocales])
    
def contarVocales():
    numvoc = (len (obtener_vocales(mensaje)))
    ventana = Tk ()
    etiqueta = Label (ventana, text = "Numero de vocales").place(x=20, y=20)
    etiqueta1 = Label (ventana, text = numvoc).place(x=50, y=50)

ventana = Tk ()
numvoc = IntVar()
mensaje = StringVar()
ventana.title("Contar vocales de un texto")
ventana.geometry("400x120")
etiquetaT = Label (ventana, text = "Ingrese su texto").place(x=20, y=20)
textocaja = Entry (ventana, textvariable= mensaje).place(x=150, y=20)
botonContar = Button (ventana, text = "Contar vocales", command = contarVocales).place(x=70, y=70)

mainloop()
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me dice esto:

> "TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función:

```
def obtener_vocales(mensaje):
    vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    return set([c for c in mensaje if c in vocales])
```

no sirve, pues retorna un `conjunto` de vocales, no la lista de vocales encontradas. Es decir, `obtener_vocales('sala')` retorna `{'a'}`, cuando lo que necesito es la lista `['a', 'a']`, ya que la letra `a` aparece dos veces.

De todas maneras dicha función no es necesaria; basta con

```
def contarVocales():
    numvoc =  len([ c for c in mensaje.get().lower() if c in 'aeiou' ])
    ventana = Tk()
    etiqueta = Label(ventana, text="Numero de vocales").place(x=20, y=20)
    etiqueta1 = Label(ventana, text=numvoc).place(x=50, y=50)
```

donde la cuenta la podemos sacar en una sola línea.

**Demo**

Ingresando la palabra `sala`, cuenta dos vocales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, en eso tenía problemas, por que no contaba las vocales.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder al contenido de la variable `mensaje` debes acceder de esta forma con la función `"get()"` de tkinter: `(mensaje.get())` con lo cual, en tu código no estás accediendo al contenido del objeto. Tu código quedaría de esta manera:

```
def obtener_vocales(mensaje):
    vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    return set([c for c in (mensaje.get()) if c in vocales])
```

Comment: El código no está contando el número de vocales; sólo retorna un `set` con las vocales que aparecen.

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que debes de hacer un `mensaje.get()` para obtener los valores de la variable y poder trabajar con ellos en la función. Prueba con esto, debería funcionar:

```
from tkinter import *


def obtener_vocales(mensaje):
    mensaje = mensaje.get()
    vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    mensaje = [c for c in mensaje if c in vocales]
    return mensaje
    
def contarVocales():
    #li = mensaje.get()
    numvoc = len(obtener_vocales(mensaje))
    ventana = Tk ()
    etiqueta = Label (ventana, text = "Numero de vocales").place(x=20, y=20)
    etiqueta1 = Label (ventana, text = numvoc).place(x=50, y=50)


ventana = Tk ()
numvoc = IntVar()
mensaje = StringVar()
ventana.title("Contar vocales de un texto")
ventana.geometry("400x120")
etiquetaT = Label (ventana, text = "Ingrese su texto").place(x=20, y=20)
textocaja = Entry (ventana, textvariable= mensaje).place(x=150, y=20)
botonContar = Button (ventana, text = "Contar vocales", command = contarVocales).place(x=70, y=70)

mainloop()
```

¡Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)